# Loading multiple URL's with different buttons using one UIWebView -- iOS Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uiwebview

I have a ViewController with a button, I was able to link it (through segue) with another ViewController that contains a UIWebView.
When I click the button, it segues into the ViewController and loads the webpage that I have specified.

This is my code in my VC that contains UIWebView:

```
func displayURL ()
    {
    let myURLString = "http://google.com"
    let myURL = NSURL(string: myURLString)
    let myURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: myURL!)
    myWebView.loadRequest(myURLRequest)   
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

           displayURL ()
    }
```

I now want to add multiple buttons that go to different Web Pages using only ONE UIWebView, but I'm not sure how to do it?

I tried doing it where I did :

```
if segue.identifier = website1
{
load website1 
} else etc..
```

but wasn't able to get it to work.

Currently, clicking the button is just seguing into the next VC, but I think I would hve to declare what website it is within the button itself.

Is there anyway to do something like:

```
if (button1 is clicked){
go to this website
}
else..
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement `prepareForSegue` and there do something like:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
let websiteController = segue.destinationViewController as YourVCName
    if segue.identifier == "website1" {
        websiteController.urlWebsite = "google.com"
    } else if segue.identifier == "website2" {
        websiteController.urlWebsite = "stackoverflow.com"
    }
}
```

The idea is having a variable in the other VC called `urlWebsite` and using it inside `displayURL`

Comment: First, place a breakpoint an check if that `prepareForSegue` is working as intended

Comment: Then, you have to create a var just where your second class starts called `urlWebsite` and used that instead of `let myURLString = "google.com"`

Comment: Excellent! got it figured out. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! ( Accepting the answer would be great :) )

Comment: Done! I did have to play around with it, a lot. Using Switch statements etc. but got it figured out. If anyone else is wondering, definitely let me know and I can explain the process.